# How can I create a DOM Element without a document?

Tags: java, jaxp

Working with JAXP, the "Hello  world" to create an element is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();

Element e = doc.createElement("helloElement");
// attributes, append, etc...
```

this makes the creation of an Element dependent of a document object. Is there any way to create an element without a particular document ? something like:

```
Element e = DomDocument.createElement("helloElement"); //static method or so ...
return e;
```

Implementing the Element interface is way too much than necessary!

the purpose is to get a DOM Element from a POJO without the need to pass a document
any suggestions ?

Comment: IMHO Element makes no sense unless its not in context of a document

Comment: I think this link may help you.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing

Comment: @saury an Element is a representation, it can be created and assigned to a context (document) later on. I just wonder if it is possible with JAXP

Comment: @Mdhar9e In what way a generic article can help ?! I have done my research!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to create an element without a particular document?

No.  The way the DOM is designed the `Document` is a factory for all the other objects, and those objects can only exist within the context of a particular `Document`.  So you're already using the correct approach by creating an empty document from the `DocumentBuilder`.

> the purpose is to get a DOM Element from a POJO without the need to pass a document

You can create your own `Document` within the POJO and use that to create elements, but then if a caller of your method wants to add the returned `Element` to their own `Document` they will first have to "adopt" it by calling `adoptNode`, as a `Document` is only allowed to contain nodes that it "owns".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Node` (which `Element` extends) provides a `getOwnerDocument()` method. Presumably you'd want to add new elements to an existing element, so you could use this method to get a reference to the parent element's document and create the new
element from there.

Comment: What about XmlAdapter.marshal() ? This can return a specific object or an element/node. But how to create element or node without context ?! I guess I have to define all my xml types and not rely on DOM instantation